# Woocommerce api only returning 20 results

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using the woocommerce apii with PHP located here `https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library`

I've tried using

1. `$all_orders =  $client->orders->get(null, array( 'post_status' => 'wc-processing') );`
2. `$all_orders =  $client->orders->get(null, array( 'post_status' => 'processing') );`
3. `$all_orders =  $client->orders->get(null, array( 'status' => 'wc-processing') );`
4. `$all_orders =  $client->orders->get(null, array( 'status' => 'processing') );`

Only 20 results are returned.  There are 71 processing orders.

How do i solve?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$all_orders =  $client->orders->get(null, array('filter[limit]' => '-1' ,'status' => 'processing') );
```

to get the all Processing orders OR

```
$all_orders =  $client->orders->get(null, array('filter[limit]' => '500' ,'status' => 'processing') );
```

to get the 500 Processing orders.